# how to save input type range to input type text

Tags: jquery, html, slider, range

how to save input type range in a input type text

```
<div class="range-slider">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="10" data-min="1" data-max="10">
</div>
```

### Jquery

how to get input type range's value and store it in a input type text?

its possible to do something like this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What research have you done? There's a ***huge*** amount of information on the 'net (and here on SO; not to mention the extensive [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com)) saying exactly how to find an `input` element in the DOM, read its value, assign a new value, ...

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
$("[type='range']").on('change',function(){
    $("[type='text']").val(this.value);
});
```